# Adding -DHAVE_LIBUDEV_H=0 argument

Tags: g++, cmake, arguments, archlinux

I've been looking for the answer for some time but couldn't find it, so here's the question:
How to add "cmake argument" written above to simple g++ command (g++ cos.cpp -lSDL2), or to Eclipse IDE?
If somebody is curious why I'm asking, here's the link to the bug I'm dealing with atm:
https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/37484

I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: I think that CMake argument would have to be added when you're building SDL2 (or more accurately configuring SDL2 prior to building it) rather than when you're linking to SDL2.